# How does timezones works in javascript?

Tags: momentjs

How does timezones works in javascript?

I'm trying to use moment.js but have some strange results.
In my zone `moment().format()` returns `2014-08-05T18:56:08+02:00`.
But this one `moment(0).format()` returns `1970-01-01T01:00:00+01:00`.

Why do the timezones differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see the timezone differences due to the Daylight Saving Time (or Summer Time).

On moment=0 you timezone was not in DST so the offset by that time was +1 (I believe this is the normal offset in your region).

Right now, in the current moment you use `moment()`, your region is in DST so your current offset is +2. That's why you see the different offsets.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Javascript, but using google I found [this link](http://momentjs.com/docs/).

It looks like passing `0` as an argument constructs a time with a `0` millisecond offset from the start of [Unix Time.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

If we go 0 milliseconds from the start of unix time, we end up at the start of unix time. Which is Thursday, 1 January 1970.